# Reading SQL query and output into shell (ARRAY), loop through and print the results

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to read a sql query results and print out the results....
Looking a second opinion...

```
sqlplus -s $database userinfo << b > abc.tmp

    set head off
    set verify off
b
    IFS=","
    select * from jobs where job no in (1, 2, 3, 4);

    while read -r col1 col2
    echo $result
    done < abc.tmp
```

RESULTS"

```
Print,  11
Delete; 5
Send,   6
```

clarification.

```
I have the output I need, but now need to process it in an array and query column values  (second)  value which is for instance print is 11.
```

If the value is less than 4, I need to echo (print that row).

For instance,

```
Print,  3
Delete; 5
Send,   6


Print,  3
```

Echo - Print job has not run...

Comment: What is the problem here?  It is not clear whether you are using heredoc `<<` to pass the query to sqlplus.

Comment: I made a first effort formatting your code, but I do not understand. I think your here-doc with `sqlplus` runs until after the `select` statement.
Show `abc.tmp` and what you want as a result of the while-loop (did you want to `echo "col1-${col1}, col2=${col2}"` ?).